# How to query group by 2 condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table here.

[image]

How can i

```
SELECT 
    sum(gload1) as 'g1',
    sum(gload2) as 'g2'.
    sum(gload3) as 'g3',
    sum(gload4) as 'g4' 
FROM member 
WHERE age = 15-20,21-25,26-30 
GROUP BY gender;
```

result like this : Just sample

[image]

How can i query like this. Thank for advamce.

Comment: Well, the first part of the answer is that you can put as many clauses as you like in the `GROUP BY` part. Putting that part in the `WHERE` makes no sense.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Member WHERE (age >= 15 AND age <= 20) OR (age >= 21 AND age <= 25) OR (age >= 26 AND age <= 30) ORDER BY gender

Comment: @andrewb That will just sort the results, not group them.

Comment: How about "show Age column" ? But, thank to answer.

Comment: Should get sum in `gload` fields ?

Comment: In what sense is your example output grouping by gender?  The gender column isn't even being displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN '15-20'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30'
        ELSE '30-...'
    END as age_group,
    gender,
    sum(gload1) as gload1_total
FROM 
    member
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN age BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN '15-20'
        WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30'
        ELSE '30-...'
    END,
    gender
```

if it doesn't work, you might have to do a subquery: inner query will add the range string to every row and outer query will group by it.

Comment: This seems like the right approach to me. Note that with this you can add `gender` to the `GROUP BY` (and `SELECT`) if you want to split the totals for men and women, which is tricky with the other approaches suggested.

Comment: @IMSoP good point, didn't notice it in the orig question, added now.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN `age`>=15 AND `age`<=20 THEN '15-20'
    WHEN `age`>=21 AND `age`<=25 THEN '21-25'
    WHEN `age`>=26 AND `age`<=30 THEN '26-30'
  END AS `AgeRange`,
  SUM(`gload1`) AS `g1`, 
  SUM(`gload2`) AS `g2`, 
  SUM(`gload3`) AS `g3`, 
  SUM(`gload4`) AS `g4`
FROM 
  member 
GROUP BY `AgeRange`
```

**See** [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f006/36)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create fake table representing the rows.  Try this:

```
SELECT AgeBrackets.Age as Age, sum(gload1) as gload1, sum(gload2) as gload2, sum(gload4) AS gload
FROM 
(SELECT '15-20' AS Age, 15 as stdt, 20 as eddt
UNION
SELECT '21-25', 21, 25
UNION
SELECT '26-30', 26, 30) AS AgeBrackets
JOIN member
ON member.age BETWEEN AgeBrackets.stdt AND AgeBrackets.eddt
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Age;
```

Comment: The above is needed because the group by clause in your original query will group all the males together and all the females together regardless of their age.